# facebook login looping around

Tags: javascript, facebook

i am using facebook javascript SDK for login button in my website it is working properly but i am missing in two use cases

1. whenever facebook cookie is available it is redirecting from index.php to event.php page even though i am firing FB.login() function on-click event.
2. when user clicks on logout button on my site i am redirecting it index.php, after loading the index.php page  it is again redirecting to event.php page

here is my code in index.php

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
  appId      : '375834632488230', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
// Additional initialization code here
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { 
window.location="http://mysite.com/event.php";

});

function doLogin(){
console.log("clicked on fb");
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
  FB.api('/me?fields=email,location,name,first_name,last_name,picture',
   function (response) {       });
  }
} , {scope:'email'}); 
}

</script>
<a href="#" id="fblogin"  class="signinfacebook" onclick="doLogin()">Sign in with
Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*answering my own question*

Remove this code :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { 
    window.location="http://mysite.com/event.php";
});
```

This should not be used in this context.

Then include this line in `FB.Login()` function :

```
if(response.status=='connected'){
    window.location="http://mysite.com/event.php";
} else {
    console.log("login failed");
}
```

i think this should work fine